# How get percentage of password protected rar file extraction in python?

Tags: python, python-2.6

i have code like this

```
        rar = rarfile.RarFile(source_filename)
        files = rar.namelist()
        count_files =len(files)
        i = 0
        for f in files:
            i = i+1

            percent = int((i/float(count_files))*100)
            rar.extract(f,dest_dir,self.pwd)
            self.emit(percent)
        rar.close()
```

I want to show the percentage of rar file extraction based in files in GUI application. this code working fine if the rar file not encrypted with password.if the rar file in protected with password .**rar.namelist()** function give always empty list. How get all file names inside password encrypted rar file?
How get percentage of password protected rar file extraction in python?

Comment: Use a `rarfile` that can work with encrypted RAR files.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams could you explain? i didn't get you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://rarfile.berlios.de/doc/rarfile.RarFile-class.html) it seems like you should use `setpassword` to give it the password.

Example:

```
rar = rarfile.RarFile(source_filename)
if rar.needs_password():
    rar.setpassword('') # whatever the password is

# Rest of code here
```

If you don't know the password, then you can't extract the files. So in that case I don't really see the point in a progress bar.